# Taking Screenshots of a Webbrowser Control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, screenshot

What is the best method to take screenshots of the webbrowser control in a win form app (C#) even if the application is not visible or computer is locked? The current method I am using (which comes from csExWB2) generates black screenshots every so often.

Comment: 22% accept, 0 votes, you are really inspiring us to help you. Expertsexchange is made for you.